# CSS Alternative for positioning

Tags: css, position, fixed, absolute, alternate

I am using positioning(fixed/absolute)due to having scroll when content overflows, but the problem is if I have to change dimension of other parts, I must change position of the scroll-able container.

As far as I know to have a box scroll-able while overflowing situation, dimension of the box must be set!

Here is my `css` for the container:

```
 .scrollable-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 152px;
    right: 0;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: good way to express your problem is to use code snippet tool

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position of a div dynamically does not affect its scrollability.Its not mandatory to position a scrollable div .

```
  .list {
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/526ctwew/

fiddle has two divs placed inline with no positioning done. Even if the scrollable div moves to next line(on resizing the screen) scrolling is not affected.

Hope this helps .

Comment: What if you stick the bottom of list to the bottom of container.